# Integrate three commands for author information (TOC, header, chapter start) into a single master-command?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, chapters, author

I'm currently working on a new LateX layout for a scientific open-access journal. I have defined three commands for author information: TOC (`\authortoc`), header (`\markauthor`) and chapter start (`\chapterauthor`). Please have a look at the minimal working example (MWE) below.

Requirements:

- Only the authors' surnames are given in the header.
- In the TOC, the authors' full names (first name, surname) are specified and separated by commas.
- The authors' full names are also specified in the chapter start. Each name is followed by a line break.

**My question is:** Is it possible to integrate the three commands into a single new master-command? So I only have to specify this command in the document (once for each chapter not three times for each chapter)?

Here follows the MWE. This is the first MWE I ever created. So please let me know, if I need to give more information or if something is unclear.

By the way, I am using LuaLaTeX for compiling.

```latex
\documentclass[%
fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%% define author header

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\authormark}{}

\newcommand*{\markauthor}[1]{%
   \renewcommand{\authormark}{#1}%
   \ignorespaces
}

%% define author chapter start

\newcommand*{\chapterauthor}[1]{%
   \par\vspace{2\baselineskip}%
   \textbf{\textsf{\protect\small#1}}%
% \markauthor{#1}% I had to uncomment this part, because otherwise the newline is written in the page header
   \par\vspace{2\baselineskip}%
   \@afterheading
}

%% define author TOC

\DeclareRobustCommand\authortoctext[1]{%
{\nopagebreak\leftskip0em\relax
\rightskip \@tocrmarg\relax
\noindent\itshape\sffamily#1\par}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\authortoc[1]{%
\addtocontents{toc}{\authortoctext{#1}}}


\usepackage[draft=false,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\lohead{\authormark}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\markauthor{Doe / Miller}%
\chapterauthor{John Doe\\
Joe Miller}%
\authortoc{John Doe, Joe Miller}%

\section*{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Thank you, Barbara!